# Does Guice Provider provide Concurrency in thread while calling two methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, dependency-injection, guice

I have a method where I am using Guice provider to provide the parameters.

```
public ModelClass somemethod(){
// contains method from provider
return something;
}
```

This method returns the Model class that contains getters to get the values .

and there is another method that should get the value from the somemethod above and then call the method

```
public ListValue someothermethod(){
//contains method from another provider
return anotherthing;
}
```

Is there anyway I can make sure that another method is being called for the same value that some method is returning? Does provider provide concurrency to get the same value even in different methods? Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by "provide concurrency"?

Comment: Does that return the value for same object I return from first method? Do I have to write multithreading to get the concurrency?

Comment: I'm with Andy. Your question is poorly phrased. You seem to be asking about whether the same *value* is used in two different places, but you're asking about concurrency, which is about doing multiple things at the same *time*. This makes no sense. Could you try adding more code to your question, showing how you're using the Guice annotations and how you want the value that the first method is returning to be used?

Comment: Also, `void` methods with return statements don't make sense.